# Executing java file using Karate Framework

Tags: karate

We have a java file that we need to execute as part of our test steps, the way we execute it is by using below java command:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -cp .:bin:target/classes:lib/jt400.jar:lib/gson-2.8.0.jar:lib/log4j.jar:lib/sentry-6.25.2.jar com.etc.ce400.JavaFile DQserver2.ini JavaFile
```

Would it be possible to execute above java command in a Karate feature?

Appreciate if you may please give/share an example or link for reference.

Thanks,

Tried searching for possible solutions but have not found any that relates to my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Karate has excellent CLI support. You should be able to use the documentation here to get started: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/cli/README.md

Comment: Thanks Peter, always appreciate the quick response :)